# C# generic type constraint depending on used constructor

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I want to mimic the Python `collections.defaultdict` in C#. The following works fine as long as the value type has a parameterless constructor:

```
public class DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue : new()
{
    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue val;
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out val)) {
                val = new TValue();
                Add(key, val);
            }
            return val;
        }
        set { base[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

But what if I want to use a constructor that takes the key as argument? Or generally, a factory function that, given the key, returns an instance of the value type?

```
public class DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue : new()
{
    private readonly Func<TKey, TValue> factory;

    public DefaultDictionary() : this(key => new TValue())
    {}

    public DefaultDictionary(Func<TKey, TValue> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue val;
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out val)) {
                val = factory(key);
                Add(key, val);
            }
            return val;
        }
        set { base[key] = value; }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that `TValue` is still required to have a parameterless constructor, even when a factory function is used. The following won't compile if `Thingy` does not have a parameterless constructor:

```
new DefaultDictionary<int, Thingy>(key => new Thingy(key, otherStuff, moreStuff));
```

However, removing the constraint will cause error CS0304 in the `new TValue()` statement.

Intuitively I would want to place the type constraint on the `DefaultDictionary()` constructor, but I doubt this is possible. Is there a proper way to solve this problem in C#?

Comment: You could go with "key = default(TValue)" or "val = default(TValue)".

Comment: This would simply assign `null` to `val`.

Comment: Or default value for struct. I don't see other way to do it, but maybe it's just my imagination not being creative enough :-)
One idea would be to remove a default constructor from DefaultDictionary and thus removing usage of default constructor of TValue

Comment: Yes, but having to explicitly write the initializer lambda in every creation of `DefaultDictionary` would be quite impractical...

Comment: How about just don't provide a parameterless constructor?

Comment: See my previous comment. Every instantiation of `DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue>` would have to be done like so: `new DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue>(key => new TValue())`, which is not very nice compared to simply writing `new DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue>()`.

Comment: you may create another class and static method for creation [like this (also using `new` to hide method has obvious downsides)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eD60hD)

Comment: I see, that looks quite idiomatic. Would you care making that into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: OP, note that you can ping @Selvin by adding an at sign before their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to keep only the constructor taking the value factory in `DefaultDictionary`, and create a subclass that does have the `: new()` constraint, and move the parameterless constructor there:

```
public class DefaultDictionaryParameterless<TKey, TValue> :
    DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue : new()
{
    public DefaultDictionaryParameterless()
        : base(x => new TValue())
    {
        
    }
}

public class DefaultDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Func<TKey, TValue> factory;

    public DefaultDictionary(Func<TKey, TValue> factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }
    ...
}
```